# Reading JSON text and outputting a Boolean depending on numeric value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Here is a little snippet of my json text which is in a column in a database.  I want to write a query that will return a Boolean value if the values for "1", "2", etc. = 0.  So if "1": 0 I want to have a false value so then I can write a conditional statement to display a message depending of the Boolean value.

```
 {
     "ENABLE": [
        {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 1,
            "3": 1,
            "4": 1
       }
   ]
    }
```

Comment: you need to tag your dbms

Comment: gotcha just updated @eshirvana

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using `jsonb` functions:

```
select jsonb_array_elements((jsonb_extract_path(jsoncolumn::jsonb,'ENABLE'))) @> '{"4":1}'::jsonb as checking
from test
```

'{"4":1}' can be parameterized, as if you make a procedure , or if you build your query as dynamic sql.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c6e2488fb8dc61a3255dbfc7b11ba0e5)*